# What methods could you use to prevent broken licensing links?

Tags: licensing

Suppose you have an open source piece of software. You decide you want to publish the software under an open source license. You spend time researching licenses online and finally you find the perfect one.

**My question:**

Are there any (better) alternatives to simply adding a link to the chosen license?

If yes, what are some examples?

If no, why not? How could I prevent a broken link?

Comment: The one foolproof way would be to copy the entire text of the license onto the software.

Comment: Related: [Do I really need to include a licence file for common licences like GPL or MIT?](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/176/190)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'll convert [my comment](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/938/what-methods-could-you-use-to-prevent-broken-licensing-links#comment1434_938) to an answer and suggest this:

Add the entire text of the license to your software, formatted like a comment (or as a separate file). This is essentially foolproof. Longer licenses would take up more space, but this should not be a problem. Licenses such as the [MIT license](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT), which are quite short, should be easy to fit in. As [Zizouz212 mentioned](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/938/what-methods-could-you-use-to-prevent-broken-licensing-links/939#comment1711_939), though, be sure to indicate that this is the text of the last updated version, in order to account for changes.

Comment: The one defect with this approach here is that the licence terms that are extended, such as GPL V3 **or later**.

Comment: @AndrewRussell That's true, I guess.

Comment: But still, It's much better than not having the license available as all. @HDE226868 Perhaps you could add a tip to have a "last updated" section when adding the entire license to the code in order to prevent the information from outdating itself?

Comment: @Zizouz212 Sure.

Comment: I don't quite get what the defect would be there?

Answer (score 1):

**Choose a well understood, common, supported and maintained Licence!**

(just like you choose your software)

I would choose one of the following:

- GPL, LGPL, AGPL licences
- Creative Commons Licences
- Apache Licence
- Eclipse Public Licence
- BSD licence

Or other [Common Licences](https://www.blackducksoftware.com/resources/data/top-20-open-source-licenses) applicable to the language/platforms you inhabit.

The organizations that support and promote these licenses are especially careful to keep the links valid. Usually, it is a key facet of the organisation's reason for existing.

Compare this to company related links:

i.e. Oracle bought Sun and refocussed around open source, I am not sure if links changed much but some licenses were almost deprecated and the licenses won't be maintained.

Comment: Couldn't those also be susceptible to broken links?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to link rot, the best solution is to archive it in the [wayback machine](http://archive.org/web/). That way, should the link ever break, you can point it to the wayback machine's archive. A good way to ensure this would be to index the page in the wayback machine whenever you publish your document with the link.

I do like @HDE 226868's suggestion of adding the license content too. I think you should combine them.

Of course this is susceptible to going down, as is any reliance on a third party solution, however I do not think the internet archive is in any danger of going away anytime soon.